# Tem um jeito mais reduzido para a resolução da questão abaixo? e saber se está correto

Tags: c, array, c++

- Crie um algoritmo que contenha um vetor de inteiros. Depois, seu algoritmo deve gerar mais dois vetores. O primeiro vetor deve armazenar os números do vetor inicial em ordem crescente e o segundo deve armazenar os valores  do vetor inicial em ordem decrescente.

código:

```
    #include <iostream>

      using namespace std;

      int main()
       {
    int vetor[5] = {8, 2, 7, 3, 6};
    int cresc[5] = {vetor[0], vetor[1], vetor[2], vetor[3], vetor[4]};
    int decre[5] = {vetor[0], vetor[1], vetor[2], vetor[3], vetor[4]};

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < (5 - 1); j++){
                if(cresc[i] < cresc[j]){
                    int aux = cresc[i];
                    cresc[i] = cresc[j];
                    cresc[j] = aux;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int a = 0; a < 5; a++){
            for(int b = 0; b < (5 - 1); b++){
                if(decre[a] > decre[b]){
                    int aux2 = decre[b];
                    decre[b] = decre[a];
                    decre[a] = aux2;
                }
            }
        }

        for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++){
            cout << "vetor crescente[" << x << "]: " << cresc[x] << "" << endl;
        }
        cout << "--------------" << endl; 
        for(int z = 0; z < 5; z++){
            cout << "vetor decrescente[" << z << "]:" << decre[z] << endl;
        }
      return 0;
     }
```

Comment: Precisa ver se tem algum enunciado que exija alguma coisa, tem algumas poucas que diminui um pouco, mas pode ser que a intenção não seja fazer assim.

Comment: Cuidado, c e c++ são linguagens completamente diferentes. Escrever em uma linguagem não quer dizer que vá funcionar na outra. A propósito, o seu programa não funciona com um compilador C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sua resolução está correta sim, no entanto consegue reduzir, optimizar e melhorar um pouco:

- Pode tornar os arrays sem ser de tamanho fixo, utilizando uma
  variável ou uma constante.
- Não precisa de fazer duas ordenações pois a ordenação crescente é inversa a decrescente. Com isto pode após a primeira ordenação copiar invertido para a segunda.
- Usando até um algoritmo de ordenação semelhante, o *insertion sort*, pode construir ambos os arrays ao mesmo tempo.

Aplicando estas modificações ficaria assim:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define TAM 5 //constante para o tamanho aqui

int main()
{
    //agora cria os arrays com base num tamanho
    int vetor[TAM] = {8, 2, 7, 3, 6};
    int cresc[TAM], decre[TAM]; 

    //agora tem de se copiar do vetor para o cresc pois o tamanho pode variar
    for (int i = 0; i < TAM; ++i){
        cresc[i] = vetor[i];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < TAM; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < TAM; j++)
        {
            if(cresc[j] < cresc[i])
            {
                int aux = cresc[i];
                cresc[i] = cresc[j];
                cresc[j] = aux;
            }
        }

        //ao mesmo tempo que constroi o cresc colocando os mais pequenos na parte inicial
        //coloca também os maiores na parte final do decre
        decre[TAM-i-1] = cresc[i];
    }

    //resto das escritas dos arrays igual
    ...

    return 0;
}
```

Poderia naturalmente utilizar algoritmos de ordenação mais eficientes como o *quicksort* ou *mergesort* que lhe garantem complexidade de O(nlogn) mas já são um pouco mais complexos e provavelmente não farão parte das soluções que esperam para o exercício.

Answer (score 4):

Bom, como vc está usando a *tag* c++, pq não resolver o problema usando o que se tem de melhor no C++?

Para o vetor, use o [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector). Para manusear os dados, o [STL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) tem vários algoritmos que vc pode usar, como por exemplo, o `std::sort`. Abaixo tem um exemplo no qual faz o que vc pede:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void imprime(const T& v)
{
    for(auto&& i : v)
        std::cout << i << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    auto vetor = std::vector<int>({8, 2, 7, 3, 6});

    auto cresc = vetor;
    std::sort(cresc.begin(), cresc.end());

    auto decre = decltype(cresc)(cresc.rbegin(), cresc.rend());

    imprime(vetor);
    imprime(cresc);
    imprime(decre);
    return 0;
}
```

Veja funcionando no [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5713867e9fd894de)

PS. Tem que se usar a versão C++11 ou superior

Answer (score 2):

Em C++98 você pode fazer algo como:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int nums[] = { 8, 2, 7, 3, 6 };


void exibir( vector<int> & v )
{
    for( vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it )
        cout << *it << " ";

    cout << endl;
}


int main( void )
{
    vector<int> vetor( nums, nums + (sizeof(nums)/sizeof(nums[0])) );

    vector<int> cresc( vetor );
    sort( cresc.begin(), cresc.end() );

    vector<int> decre( cresc );
    reverse( decre.begin(), decre.end() );

    exibir( vetor );
    exibir( cresc );
    exibir( decre );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solução em C:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int qsort_crescent( const void * a, const void * b ) { return *((int*)a) - *((int*)b); }
int qsort_decrescent( const void * a, const void * b ) { return *((int*)b) - *((int*)a); }


void exibir( int array[], int tam )
{
    int i = 0;

    for( i = 0; i < tam; i++ )
        printf( "%d ", array[i] );

    printf("\n");
}


int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    int vetor[5] = { 8, 2, 7, 3, 6 };

    int cresc[5];
    int decre[5];

    memcpy( cresc, vetor, sizeof(vetor) );
    qsort( cresc, 5, sizeof(int), qsort_crescent );

    memcpy( decre, vetor, sizeof(vetor) );
    qsort( decre, 5, sizeof(int), qsort_decrescent );

    exibir( vetor, 5 );
    exibir( cresc, 5 );
    exibir( decre, 5 );

    return 0;
}
```